# /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory error upon executing shell script

Tags: java, bash

I am using a tool called Multicraft to manage game server instances for development purposes. Multicraft allows a startup script, to initialize the server. However, upon trying to use java within the script, I receive an error that No file or Directory is found.

Command: `/bin/bash /home/kraft/test.sh '/usr/bin/java -version'`

Error: `/home/kraft/test.sh: line 2: '/usr/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
$($@)
```

I can run `java -version` just fine when I use the `su` command to change to the multicraft user that would be running the script. Additionally, I dug and found the command `ldd /usr/bin/java`, this returns

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd49bf6000)
libjli.so => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9e14ad9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9e150cd000)
```

I assume this means a dependency is not working correctly, however upon doing `locate libjli.so` the file is indeed found within the JDK 17 folder.

In the end, I would like to execute a jar file from within this script, instead of trying to view the version of java.

Comment: try `which java`?

Comment: @00001H Running java 17

Comment: what does `which java` return?

Comment: The `java` you use when you type it in your shell can be some other executable than `/usr/bin/java`.  Check if `/usr/bin/java` exists, and based on what you put, it does not. Then run `which java` in your terminal, and modify your script to point to that specific path.